# Get post_content as a string

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api

I have an array of posts from an WPQuery by doing

```
$query = new WPQuery(.....)
$array_of_posts = $query->post_content
```

However this is returning the content as HTML as with some other stuff too

```
<!-- wp:paragraph -->
<p>the text</p>
<!-- /wp:paragraph -->
```

And then i want to display this as content for each post in the array

```
foreach($array_of_posts as $post){
  <h1> echo $post->post_content </h1>
```

But of course this just gives me a h1 with the html and other stuff. How can i just get the string?

Also this code is just pseudo code i know the syntax is wrong

Answer (score 1):

---

### You're looking `wp_strip_all_tags()`

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_strip_all_tags/*

> Properly strip all HTML tags including script and style. This differs from strip_tags() because it removes the contents of the `<script>` and `<style>` tags. *E.g. `strip_tags( '<script>something</script>' )` will return `‘something’`. `wp_strip_all_tags` will return `‘’`*

```
echo wp_strip_all_tags( the_content() );
```

Alternatively , you could use `remove_filter('term_description','wpautop');` in your `function.php` to remove the `<p>` tags.

Comment: I ended up using strip_tags(), Is there anyway to use the_content() ?It gives me an error

Comment: `the_content()` should be use to display the post content.